# Why second example does not work properly

Tags: python

```
def collect_num(s):
    ''' (str) -> str

    retruns the phone num from the string s.

    >>> collect_num('my phone mumber is 01120190637')
    01120190637
    >>> collect_num('My number in 2020 is 01007332209')
    01007332209
    '''

    num = ''

    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit() and s[s.find(char):s.find(char) + 11].isdigit():
            num = s[s.find(char):s.find(char) + x]

            return num
```

When I execute the second example, the program returns 1007332209 without the first zero. Why?

Comment: As an aside, **for readability and performance sake**, use local variables. You keep calling `s.findchar(char)` over and over again. You only ever need to call it once. Use `digit_index = s.findchar(char)`.

Comment: The problem is with this line `s[s.find(char):s.find(char) + 11]` actually you are getting `s 010073322, 
 number in ,
020 is 0100,
1007332209`

Comment: In second does not yield because ```2020``` is also a number & apply isdigit returns true, which will be taken as start index.

Comment: Notice, `.find` finds **the first occurrence of something in a string.**. As an alternative, you can just iterate with the index instead of using `.find`. This is a common source of bugs...

Comment: Why it works at all is a mystery without knowing what `x` is.

Comment: why not use regex, ```re.search("\d{10,}",'my phone mumber is 01120190637').group()```

Comment: Have you considered using regexes? After `import re`, this should give you the number from a line: `re.search(r"\d{5,}", s).group()` (it gets the first number from the text that has 5 or more digits)

Answer (score 2):

The core of the problem is the `s.find(char)` portion. In your example

```
'My number in 2020 is 01007332209'
```

Notice that there the character `'0'` occurs in 2020 as well as the cell phone number. Therefore, `s.find('0')` will return the position of 0 in 2020, not the beginning of the cell phone number. According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html), `str.find()` will

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s

The lowest index in this case is the 0 that occurs in 2020.

For OP's reference, here is an alternative implementation that uses `enumerate()` for explicit indexing.

```py
def collect_num(s):
    for i, _ in enumerate(s):
        candidate = s[i: i + 11]
        if candidate.isdigit():
            return candidate
    return -1 # Signifies no cell phone number found
```

Comment: what is the enumerate() and how can I find it?

Comment: `enumerate()` is a way of looping over iterables while indexing at the same time. I recommend that you check out [this post](https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-enumerate/) for some examples. If you're thrown off by it, we can replace `for i, _ in enumerate(s)` with `for i in range(len(s))`; they are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

To get a contiguous string of numbers of length 5 or more from a string:

```
import re

def collect_num(s):
    return re.search(r"\d{5,}", s).group()

print(collect_num('my phone number is 01120190637'))
print(collect_num('my number in 2020 is 01007332209'))
```

Result:

```
01120190637
01007332209
```